# Master - Detail dataset in Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.2

Tags: c++, c++builder

I use the DBNagivator to navigate through a master data set that is assigned as master data source to many detail data sets. The problem is there are foreign keys referenced in detail data sets that link back to the master data set. When creating a new record via the DBNavigator button, upon posting the order of post is totally the opposite of what is natural! It saves the detail first instead of master then detail sets.

I am not sure how to get over this without modifying the database and remove all foreign keys references. Even if I invoke masterData->Post() in the detail table onBeforePost action does not help.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Is there a way to make the navigator apply changes to master first then propagate down?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you indexing the foreign keys? If not, I believe adding indexing will solve your issue. See here: https://www.sqlshack.com/index-foreign-key-columns-sql-server/

Edited to add: Since Foreign Keys are Indexed, try using an event handler to make the detailed view. This is accomplished by creating a cloned cursor of the master table. If this doesn't work, try hiding the detail view and only displaying the master table unless you specifically need the detailed view for some reason? Then just use the keys for lookup? Sorry, I don't have any other ideas!

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
if not FileExists(ClientDataSet1.FileName) then
begin
  ShowMessage('Cannot find ' + ClientDataSet1.FileName +
    '. Please assign the items.cds table ' +
    'to the FileName property of ClientDataSet1 ' +
    'before attempting to run the application again');
    Halt;
end;
ClientDataSet1.Open;
//Assign the OnDataChange event handler _after_
//opening the ClientDataSet
DataSource1.OnDataChange := DataSource1DataChange;
//Clone the detail cursor.
ClientDataSet2.CloneCursor(ClientDataSet1, True);
//Create and assign an index to the cloned cursor
ClientDataSet2.AddIndex('PartIndex','PartNo',[]);
ClientDataSet2.IndexName := 'PartIndex';
ClientDataSet2.Filtered := True;
//Invoke the OnDataChange event handler to
//create the detail view
DataSource1DataChange(Self, PartFld);
end;
```

Comment: It is indexed. The issue is the application try to save the detail tables before the master table... How did they come up with this logic? It makes no sense to me...

Comment: Thank you but you're thinking of it as a master-detail view application. In my case, it's more like master-detail data sets. Example, I have a form with bunch of text inputs. On this form, I have a master data source which is the client table that contains some info and it has the primary key that gets created after you insert a row. That data set is the data source for the DBNavigator button and as I scroll through the records, it populates the data on the form. So, the detail data sets have in their property the client data set as the master source (data source) that gives the primary key.

Comment: When I save the record, I need to save the master source first so I can have the primary key then I can add it to the detail data sets before they save. What's happening is when I click save on DBNav it saves the detail data sets (children) before it saves the master. I was hoping this works out of the box without major code to be put... I hope my question is more clear to you now and thank you for trying.

Comment: I was thinking of it as an application - any way you could post some dummy data with fields so I can get an idea of what you are working with inheritance structure wise?